# fluidRow won't appear under mainPanel graphic in Shiny

Tags: r, layout, shiny, fluid-layout

I've created a Shiny app using a fluid grid system (i.e., using `fluidPage`) that utilizes `sidebarPanel` and `tabsetPanel`. In addition to the input "control" widgets I put in the sidebar, I would also like to add a series of input widgets *below* the graphic in my main panel on a specific panel.

My approach was to simply include a `fluidRow` with multiple columns after the `plotOutput` command in the first `tabPanel`.

My code produces no errors, but for some reason *nothing* shows up under the graphic in my main panel.

Is this just not possible, or am I doing something wrong?

Note: this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26308011/rshiny-display-multiple-inputs-and-text) suggests that my approach to including multiple UI elements within the tab is valid, and this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27382840/shiny-multiple-outputs-to-mainpanel?rq=1) suggests that multiple outputs can be added to the mainPanel (but what about inputs??). So what gives??

Example code with same issue:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

  titlePanel(
    h1("NMS Comparing tool", style = "font-size: 15px")
  ),


  sidebarPanel(width = 3,
           div(style = "font-size: 8px;", 
               sliderInput(inputId = "groups", 
                           label = "No. of Groups",
                           value = 4, min = 2, max = 12)
           ),  

           fluidRow(
             column(6,offset=0,
                    div(style = "height: 105px; padding: 0px 0px",
                        plotOutput(outputId = "scree")
                    )
             ),

             column(6,offset=0,
                    div(style = "font-size: 8px;padding: 0px 10px;height: 105px",
                        checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "labels",
                                           label = "Labels",
                                           choices = c("SPEC","Plot-End","Plot-Start"),
                                           selected = c("SPEC","Plot-End","Plot-Start")
                        )    
                    )
             )
           ),

           fluidRow(
             column(6,offset=0,
                    div(style = "font-size: 8px; padding: 0px 0px",      
                        radioButtons(inputId = "data",
                                     label = "Data",
                                     choices = c("PSP Only","PSP + MAP"),
                                     selected = "PSP + MAP")
                    )    
             ),

             column(6,offset=0,
                    div(style = "font-size: 8px;padding: 0px 10px;",  
                        radioButtons(inputId = "freq",
                                     label = "Frequency",
                                     choices = c(0.025,0.05),
                                     selected = 0.05)
                    )
             )
           ),

           fluidRow(
             column(6,offset=0,
                    div(style = "font-size: 8px; padding: 0px 0px; ",                 
                        radioButtons(inputId = "arrows",
                                     label = "Vector Choice",
                                     choices = c("Cumulative Change","All Samples","Hurricane"),
                                     selected = "Cumulative Change")
                    )
             ),

             column(6,offset=0,
                    div(style = "font-size: 8px;padding: 0px 10px",      
                        selectInput(inputId = "size",
                                    label = "Tree Size",
                                    choices = c("All","Canopy","Subcanopy","Small"),
                                    selected = "All"),
                        tags$style(type = "text/css",
                                   "#size {height: 4px; }")
                    )
             )
           ),

           fluidRow(
             div(style = "font-size: 8px;",                 
                 verbatimTextOutput("info")
             )    
           )
           ,

           mainPanel(width = 9,
                     tabsetPanel(
                       tabPanel(title = "NMS", 
                                plotOutput(outputId = "nms", click = "plot_click"),
                                fluidRow(
                                  column(2,offset=0,
                                         div(style = "font-size: 8px; padding: 0px 0px", 
                                             actionButton(inputId = "plot.singles", label = "Lookup")
                                         )
                                  ),
                                  column(2,offset=0,
                                         div(style = "font-size: 8px; padding: 0px 0px",     
                                             textInput(inputId = "individ", label = "Plot(s)")
                                         )
                                  ),
                                  column(2,offset=0,
                                         div(style = "font-size: 8px; padding: 0px 0px", 
                                             textInput(inputId =  "group.choose", label = "Group(s)")
                                         )
                                  ),
                                  column(3,offset=0,
                                         div(style = "font-size: 8px; padding: 0px 0px", 
                                             sliderInput(inputId = "lwidth.choose", label = "LineWidth",min = 1, max = 6)
                                         )
                                  )
                                )
                       ),
                       tabPanel(title = "Silhouette", plotOutput(outputId = "silhouette")),
                       tabPanel(title = "Indicator Spp", dataTableOutput(outputId = "ind.spp")),
                       tabPanel(title = "Data", dataTableOutput(outputId = "nms.data.table"))
                     )
           )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output) {

 output$scree <- renderPlot({

    par(mar = c(1.5,1.4,0.1,0.1), mgp = c(0.5,0.01,0), tcl = -0.1)
    plot(runif(99),runif(99),cex.axis=0.5,cex.lab=0.5,cex=0.75)

  },height = 95, width = 135) 

  output$nms <- renderPlot({

    plot(runif(99),runif(99))

  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Was your silhouette plot working. I get a blank plot, with no clusters, only text

Comment: @vipin8169 unfortunately i still have never gotten silhouette plots to work. They always come up blank for me, too. I welcome you to open a question about this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Certainly what you're trying to do is possible. When I run your example code, I actually do see the widgets underneath the plot (Lookup, Plot(s), Group(s), etc.). But I had to fix a couple of small things first--for one thing, you need to give a value to `sliderInput`. For another, you've got a misplaced bracket that's causing the `mainPanel` to be shoved into your `sidebarPanel`.

But there's no problem with your `fluidRow` itself, as written. Make sure you've put it in the right place in the UI.